# how to print number of occurences of element of an 1d array

Tags: java

I have worked on this but I keep getting an exception.  Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
package assingment;

public class frequencyCount {

    static void count(int x[]){
        System.out.println("ENTERED ARRAY IS ");
        for( int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(x[i]);
        }
        int c[] = new int [x.length];
        for(int i=0; i<c.length ;i++)
        { c[i] = 0;
        }
        for(int i=0; i< x.length ;i++){
            int m= x[i];
            c[m]++;
        }
        System.out.println("frequency table");
        for(int i=0; i< c.length ;i++){

            System.out.print(i + " "+ c[i]);

        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            count(new int []{1,1,5,2,10});

    }

}
```

Comment: Great place to use a HashMap<Integer, Integer> if we're going for a small footprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are incorrectly allocating the space to store your counts properly.  What you need is to create an array where the total number of elements is the **maximum** of your array, plus 1 to account for 0.  I'm going to assume that all of your numbers are positive to make things simple.  As such, you actually need to determine what the maximum value is in your array first, then allocate the space accordingly.

By not doing this, when you specify the value of `5` in your array, you only allocated an array of size `5`, and so if you try using `5` to index into your array, you get an `OutOfBounds` exception as you are trying to access the sixth position of the array, where it doesn't exist.

FWIW, there are much more smarter ways to do this, such as using a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), but I'm assuming you haven't covered more advanced data structures in your Java course yet, and you probably need a solution with arrays.  However, I completely recommend using `HashMap`.

As such, modify your code to find the maximum first, then allocate accordingly:

```
package assingment;

public class frequencyCount {

    static void count(int x[]){
        System.out.println("ENTERED ARRAY IS ");
        // NEW - To store maximum
        int maxi = -1;
        for( int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(x[i]);
            // Keep checking for the maximum
            if (x[i] > maxi)
                maxi = x[i];
        }        

        // NEW - modify length to account for maximum
        int c[] = new int [maxi+1];
        for(int i=0; i<c.length ;i++)
        { 
            c[i] = 0;
        }
        for(int i=0; i< x.length ;i++){
            int m= x[i];
            c[m]++;
        }
        System.out.println("frequency table");
        for(int i=0; i< c.length ;i++){         
            System.out.println(i + " "+ c[i]);          
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        count(new int []{1,1,5,2,10});     
    }    
}
```

Comment: i m also getting problem in end result ...output is looking wired ...can u help on that?

Comment: Use `System.out.println` not `System.out.print`.  `ln` means that it will make a new line per print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `c[m]` where `m=x[i]` in 3rd cycle. But `x[2]=5` and `c[5]` causes an exception since there are only 5 elements in `c[]` (from `c[0]` to `c[4]`)

Comment: thanks i got ur point